# How to put if condition in ON DELETE CASCADE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't really understand SQL language and I have a condition in one of my tables which i can't understand how i can tackle this issue. It would be great if someone could help me with it. The issue is I want a IF condition with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

"if a patient is removed
from the system, then the patient’s appointments are also
removed from the system; and, a doctor can only be removed
from the system if the doctor has no appointments."

I'm currently using `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the patient FOREIGN KEY but i'm not sure of the condition i will be using for doctor as it needs to check before doing `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: your table definitions (with constraints) would help this question greatly...

Comment: The larger issue is removing data, these are historical events; in a professional setting you should not delete these records, not just because it relates to patient data, but because these things happened in time. I would encourage you to look at other options, such as 'soft deletes', or at least an audit schema with tracking tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't put any `ON DELETE` clause for the foreign key for doctor. Any try to delete a doctor who is still referenced by an appointment will fail, as it would violate the foreign key. Only, if there is no more reference in the appointments to them, a doctor can be deleted.